# Roommate has 6+ IP adresses and clogs the network

Tags: router, ip-address

I hope this is the correct place to ask this question.

One of my roommates' computer is shown on the router having 6+ IPv4 adresses. Yesterday evening it went up to 9. It seems he gets them one by one (I saw him with 6, 8 and 9 yesterday).

Problem is, I am plugged in to the router via an ethernet cable, and when he's connected to the router the ping delay to the router is insane. [image: router ping].

When he's not there, the ping delay is < 1ms.

He says he wasn't aware of it, could this be a configuration of his network adapters ? One of the programmes he's using (he games a lot) ?

The router model is Technicolor TG784n v3, and it doesn't allow tracking of bandwidth usage unfortunately.

Comment: The only way he could be assigned that many ip addresses at the sametime would be if he had 9 adapters.  However, you have supplied any evidence that him being assigned these addresses, are the reason you have high a ping to the router.  Your typical consumer home router can deal with much more then 10 devices before being bottleknecked.

Comment: So, does he use pirated software or anything the like? His PC might be part of a botnet.

Comment: @Ramhound, what else could be the cause of such a high router ping ?

Comment: @DanielB not that I know of

Comment: @Ramhound "The only way... would be if he had 9 adapters." That's wrong, because you can manually assign more than one address per adapter.

Comment: I meant to say you "had not provided" evidence to high ping times to your device are caused by other devices on the network

Comment: @harper - There isn't much effort to support that is the case though.

Comment: @harper we checked his adapter settings, there was no manual assignment of multiple IPs. Plus he seems to get more and more until we reset the router...

Comment: I just said that the statement is wrong.

Comment: So did you scan for viruses etc yet? You could also boot some live Linux DVD/USB and see what happens.

Comment: @DanielB It would seem viri are out of the equation... Do you mean boot the router on some linux ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if there is a newer firmware for your router.
Tell him to use a manual IP configuration instead of DHCP or autoconfiguration.
If he has different IP addresses assigned, then it needs different MAC addresses too; do you see different MAC addresses assigned to each one of those IPs?
Try to match the MAC addresses to his PC, because maybe there is an intruder on the network.

Comment: He has only one MAC adress and several IPv4 and one IPV6 assigned.  I'll check for an update of the router's firmware, how do I actually do that ? Maybe we can also try with manual IP.